# How to acquire class level lock on some overriden method in C#

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I need to override a method and acquire class level lock on this method. I want only one thread from multiple instances to enter this method at a time. Could someone please guide me how to achieve this?

I tried to make a static flag(lock) and check it inside overridden method's body. But that doesn't seems to be a good idea.

```
class A
{
   protected virtual void Navigate()
   {
      //some stuff
   }
}
class B: A
{
    protected override void Navigate()
    {
       base.Navigate();
       //some suff
    }
}
```

Note: I cannot modify class A.

Comment: `I want only one thread from multiple instances to enter this method at a time` To be clear, let's say there were 2 different instances of the class in memory (lets call them Bob and Cathy). Should a call to Bob **also** block calls to Cathy?

Comment: Wht does a lock not seem to be a good idea?

Comment: _"Note: I cannot modify class A."_ You're busted. You can always derive a subclass that will call `base.Navigate()` unguarded.

Comment: @mjwills, yes a call to Bob block calls to Cathy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use lock... But this requires that A is never ever derived from another class, which would override the lock functionality.

```
class A
{          
   protected virtual void Navigate()
   {
      //some stuff          
   }
}
class B: A
{
    private static object navLock = new object();

    protected override void Navigate()
    {
       lock(navLock) 
       {
         base.Navigate();

         //some stuff
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes.. made the lock static.

Comment: What if A is derived from some other class. In that case isn't it possible to apply class level lock on overridden function?

Comment: Well.. yes and no, if you cannot change the class A. You need to use a shared navLock between those different derived classes of A.